# Появление блока при наведении на другой блок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. 
Подскажите как решить такую задачку. Нужно чтобы при наведении на картинку-ссылку в нужном блоке div появлялась информация по которой также можно кликать и т.д. Проблем реализовать появление при наведении нет, но проблема в том, что ссылки-картинки расположены в 2 ряда и если навести на картинку из нижнего ряда, то информация появившаяся для этого блока (а появляется она в div над всеми картинками-ссылками) пока будешь вести мышку до нее может исчезнуть так как легко зацепить другую ссылку-картинку.
Сайт [тут](http://znpart92.bget.ru/) Там где сейчас написан Оригинальные запчасти и должна появляться инфа, а ссылки картинки - под ней.

```
    Вот такая реализация у меня, как переписать с учетом проблем описанных выше: 
http://jsfiddle.net/werty1001/ysjptcus/
```

**UPD1:** Почему хочется именно при наведении? Потому что при клике хочется вывести модальное окно с формой. Также при клике в появившемся блоке будет так же выходить модальное окно с формой. Поэтому и хочется сделать появление при наведении, если возможно.

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by werty1001</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
  a{color:#00F;border-bottom:dotted 1px blue;margin:0 10px}
  a:hover{color:#333;border:#333;cursor:pointer}
  .help{width:100px;height:100px;display:inline-block;background:#eee;padding:20px;margin:0 10px;opacity:0}
  .help.active{opacity:1}
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function() {
    var id, pause = 300;
    $("body").on("mouseenter", "[data-help]", function(b) {
        id = $(this).data("help");
        this.pause = pause;
        $(this).stop(!0).animate({
            pause: 0
        }, pause, function() {
            id == $(this).data("help") && ($(".help").removeClass("active"), $(id).addClass("active"))
        })
    }).on("mouseleave", "[data-help]", function(b) {
        id = null
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a data-help="#log1">Ссылка №1</a>
<a data-help="#log2">Ссылка №2</a> <br /><br />
<div id="log1" class="help">Блок 1</div>
<div id="log2" class="help">Блок 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможно в данном случае делать не по hover, а по клику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать hover не только для ссылки, но и для блока, который показывается при наведении на ссылку. И при помощи css-анимации дать достаточно времени, чтобы довести мышку до блока (т. е. сделать задержку исчезновения).

Comment: Думал над этим, а зачем hover блоку который показываться будет? И в таком случае как отловить событие, что пользователь реально хочет показать другой блок - навел на другой пункт специально? Получается проще все реализовать через событие click?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-title{
  width:250px;
  height:180px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid #f9f9f9;
}
.image-title:hover .title{
  top:-180px;
}
.image-title img{
  max-width:250px;
  min-width:250px;
  height:200px;
}
.title{
 width:250px;
 height:200px;
 background:rgba(100,110,120,.5);
 position:relative;
}
.title p{
 text-align:justify;
 color:#fff;
 padding:5px 10px;
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="image-title"> 
      <img src="http://st2-fashiony.ru/pic/battle/pic/87130/3.jpg" alt="pic" />
   <div class="title">
     <p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  </p>
   </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

вот так ?

Comment: Вы сам сайт смотрели?

Comment: сейчас посмотрел -- и что там ? просто фоты и всё , в общем я понял что не так ?

Comment: Причём тут появление блока на этой картинке? Блок должен появляться там где сейчас написано оригинальные запчасти. А наведение на блоки с картинками под ней.